# Google Instant Preview Testing Tool

Tags: google-instant-previews

My pages are broken on Google Instant Preview, and I **think** I fixed it... in order to be sure I'd need a testing took for that...
So far I couldn't find such a tool. Does anyone know of a way how to test it?

Google did a great job with the [Rich Snippets Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173839), but I had no luck in finding a testing tool for Instant Preview...

Important to mention: I have a "noscript" tag, that redirects all JavaScript-disabled requests to a different URL... but the image Google shows doesn't show the final target; instead it shows some red error message which I cannot even read...

Comment: Sucks that we have to make our webpages work with google instant preview

Comment: That's right, but I'm still convinced that it is better for searchers to see a snapshot from the landing page... Google drives us crazy, but they still please their users...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem:
My customers were complaining that my website does not load with Opera browser; they said that Opera returns an "Invalid XML" error.

Once I fixed all XHTML issues on my website, and my browser looked good on Opera, the Google Instant Preview was fixed as well...